# Zip code not working - memory error

Tags: python, debugging, unzip

Can someone point out any errors I might have included in my code.  I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible but it's failing with a memory error.  Some of the compressed files do extract fine though...

```
import zipfile
import from os.path isdir, join, normpath, split
print "Unzipping data"
z = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\Incoming\\MyZipFile.zip", 'r')
print z.namelist()
for each in z.namelist():
   if not each.endswith('/'):
      root, name = split(each)
      print name
      file(join("C:\\Incoming\\", name), 'wb').write(z.read(each))
z.close()
```

The actual error message generated is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Scripts\\Zip_import_test.py", line 30, in <module>
   file(join("C:\\Incoming\\", name), 'wb').write(zip.read(each))
File "C:\\Python25\lib\zipfile.py, line 501, in read
   bytes = dc.decompress(bytes)
Memory Error
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
Frank Ogiamien

Comment: what is the size of the zip objects you're trying to unzip ?

Comment: The .zip files I'm hoping to extract from range in size up to 500meg.   My test example is 73meg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call it `zip`! You're masking the builtin.

Also, is `zip.close()` really inside your `for` loop? It shouldn't be.

You should use the `extract` method of the ZipFile object, so you don't need to read the whole file into memory.

Instead of

```
file(join("C:\\Incoming\\", name), 'wb').write(zip.read(each))
```

do

```
zip.extract(each, "C:\\Incoming\\")
```

Edit: This was added in 2.6, as was  `extractall` if you just want to extract the whole thing to a directory.

If you can't upgrade, the code in [How to simulate ZipFile.open in Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781261/how-to-simulate-zipfile-open-in-python-2-5) (in the question, not an answer) will let you use parse the zipfile and extract the data using zlib without reading it in to memory.

Comment: Hi, I changed my "zip" to "z" and tried your suggestion of using z.extract(each, "C:\\Incoming\\") however I get a new error: AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute 'extract'" Is this because my version 2.5 of py is too old?     Oh, my zip.close() wasn't really inside the for loop.  typo.

Comment: agf, thanks very much for your time.  Your comments were very helpful.  It looks like I'm better off upgrading to 2.6 if I want to keep the code short and simple.  Frank