# Where is ZipFile.open in Jython 2.5.3b1?

Tags: jython

Please, observe:

```
PS Z:\dev\poc\SDR> jython.bat
Jython 2.5.3b1 (2.5:5fa0a5810b25, Feb 22 2012, 12:39:02)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_27
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> z=ZipFile('d:/ookla/us_aaa.zip')
>>> z.open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute 'open'
>>> ZipFile.open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class ZipFile has no attribute 'open'
>>>
```

So, where is the `open` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available. [ZipFile.open](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) was added in Python 2.6, but Jython is still at version 2.5.

The method has been added in the [Jython development repository](http://hg.python.org/jython/file/tip/Lib/zipfile.py).

See also [How to simulate ZipFile.open in Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781261).